# How do I remove duplicates AND the originals from a list in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

`Edit > Permute Lines > Unique` is great for removing duplicate from a list in Sublime Text. But what if I wanted to remove **all** matching results instead? For example:

```
james
james
bobby
mary
ann
ann
```

The above list of names would become:

```
bobby
mary
```

Because `bobby` and `mary` are the only names that only appear once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't mind your lines being sorted, you could do it like this:

1. Edit > Sort Lines
2. Find > Replace...
3. Ensure RegEx mode is on
4. *Find What:* `(^.*$\n)\1+`
5. *Replace With:* (blank)

Although, sorting wouldn't be necessary if all the duplicates are next to each other, as per your example. e.g. it would even work with the following:

```
james
james
bobby
mary
ann
ann
james
james
james
```

Note that this regex requires the last line to have a trailing newline character, if it is a duplicate, otherwise it won't find it.

Comment: Thanks! I had my fingers crossed for a built-in function or an installable package. But this gets the job done too.